# Disable PHP execution in a directory without affect subdirectories using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I saw here some replies about disabling PHP execution in a direction and it affects all sub-directories inside. 
If I have a directory like that

```
/home/public_html/main/
  /home/public_html/main/sub1/
  /home/public_html/main/sub2/
  /home/public_html/main/sub3/
```

I need to make the .htaccess affect only the content of /main/ folder and let the sub-directories continue to execute PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the option simular to :

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler None
</FilesMatch>
```

This would reside in your 'main' folder, although its not a great solution as you cant be sure the user will not change the extension to get around this -> You could add a lot of regex but again not pleasant !

Once you know what the server recognizes as PHP you can complete this.

Comment: I tried but it is not working, i found something on Drupal website but it needs to specify each sub-directory in .htaccess file. I cannot do that because there are many sub-directories and new ones are added everyday.

Comment: have you considered writing a .htaccess file to the folder when it is created as a default -> What you are trying to do is a little awkward.. Maybe exec permissions on the '/main/' folder could be removed ?